General Solution of Dirichlet Problem on a Jordan Domain
I am trying to find a proof (or related materials) for the Theorem 3.4 in this paper by Mervin E. Muller. The theorem is stated as follows:
Let $D$ be a Jordan domain, with boundary $\Gamma$. Let $f(\zeta)$ be a real-valued continuous function defined on $\Gamma$. Then for any $\zeta_0 \in D$ the value $u(\zeta_0)$ of the solution of the Dirichlet problem for domain $D$ and boundary values $f(\zeta)$ is obtained by
$$
u(\zeta_0) = \int_{\Gamma} \Pr(\zeta_0, d\zeta, D) f(\zeta)
$$
where $\Pr(\zeta_0, d\zeta, D)$ is the probability density of a Brownian motion starting from $\zeta_0$ meeting $\Gamma$ (being the boundary of $D$) for the first time at $d \zeta$. I have also consulted the original paper by Kakutani (Theorem 3) but no proof is provided there either. Any help is greatly appreciated!
